# How to show two square images side by side in Plotly using px.imshow?

Tags: python, plotly

I have two square images, stored as numpy arrays, both 256 x 256 x 3. I'm able to use `px.imshow` to show each image in its own single image, and it's a nice square plot. However, when I use subplots to place both side-by-side, the first is a square as intended, but the second is always a rectangle. It's as if it is trying to fill the remaining space, instead of simply placing the output of `px.imshow`.

I've tried playing around with the input to `make_subplots`, like setting `shared_yaxes=True` and `shared_xaxes=True`, etc. I even tried forcing the figure size in the `update_layout`, with the width twice as much as the height, but this failed as well. Interestingly, if I increase the width, it seems to get more like a square, but still not exactly.

**How would I force the two images to show as squares?**

I've placed some dummy code below and shown where I'm currently at.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

im1 = np.random.random(size=(256, 256, 3))
im2 = np.random.random(size=(256, 256, 3))

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_yaxes=True, horizontal_spacing=0.01)
fig.add_trace(px.imshow(im1).data[0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(px.imshow(im2).data[0], row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(width=600, height=300, autosize=False)
fig.show()
```

[image: 600 width, 300 height]

Doubling the width and the height to 1200 and 600 respectively, leads to something more "correct", but it doesn't seem like the way to go about it.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to automatically expand if the aspect ratio is different. If the aspect ratio is the same, it will be as intended. Try this: `fig.update_layout(width=600, height=600, autosize=False, template='plotly_dark')`

Comment: Hi @Rangumi, I provided an answer below but it seems you didn't notice it. Let me know if it works for you, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`scaleanchor`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-scaleanchor) constraint explicitly. By default, all image traces have `yaxis: {scaleanchor: "x"}` set by default in order for pixels to be rendered as squares, but here setting `shared_yaxes=True` also adds a [`matches`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-matches) constraint on the second y axis, which prevent its scale anchor to be applied (an axis cannot have both constraint), so you got square pixels for the first image, but not for the second one.

The solution is to set the constraint on the x axis instead :

```py
fig.update_layout(width=600, height=300, xaxis2_scaleanchor="y2")
```

---

Note you can build the whole figure in one line by leveraging px `facet_<*>` parameters, and by doing this the different constraints are handled properly so you don't have to (re)set them afterwards :

```py
fig = px.imshow(np.array([im1, im2]), facet_col=0, aspect='equal', facet_col_spacing=0.01)
fig.update_layout(width=600, height=300)
```